# How to use stash to Preload replace?

Tags: stash, ee5

I am trying to get the current entry's related entries by using stash

main article full view:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" dynamic="yes"}
{exp:stash:get name="my_custom_field"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Related article list:

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" search:my_custom_field="{exp:stash:get name="my_custom_field"}"}
<li>{title}</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: You'll get better answers to your questions if you provide some information about what version of EE (and any add-ons) you are using; the differences in EE versions can be significant factors in how the question is answered.

Comment: what the error you are facing or which thing that you can not achieve?